# Magento 2.4.2 - Create button for Notify me when this product is in stock

Tags: magento2.4, custom-button, stock-alert

How do I change "Notify me when this product is in stock" text into a button?

I have duplicated `/vendor/magento/module-product-alert/view/frontend/templates/product/view.phtml` to local theme.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use below updated code inside the file in your local theme.

```
<div class="product alert <?= $block->getHtmlClass() ?>">
<button type="button"
        onclick="location.href='<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getSignupUrl()) ?>'"
        title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__($block->getSignupLabel())) ?>"
        class="action alert">
    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__($block->getSignupLabel())) ?>
</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfecty. Thank you so much!